# How to detect an AJAX request in a EE4 template?

Tags: templates, conditionals, ajax, ee4

What's the best practive to detect an AJAX request in EE4 without activating PHP in the template?

With the previous version of EE, I used the Ajax Detect Conditional ({if ajax}, {if not_ajax}) from Mo'Variables, but the add-on is not EE4 compatible.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native [`{is_ajax_request}` variable](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/single_variables.html#is-ajax-request).